# Smaller apa106 led, more smd style

Tags: microcontroller, led

This is going to sound like a childish question as it is not a very long one, but is there anything like a apa106 led or at least follows the same protocol coding wise that is more smd style and smaller, not like the ws2812 (i cant think of the full name) led. Smaller.

Comment: I don't know any other parts like that in SMD because the chip area would block the light in small rectangle  so you have options like PWM and Digital LED driver chips for those.  https://www.google.com/search?q=shiftregister+programmable+LEDs&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab

Comment: You are probably thinking Adafruit Neopixel

Comment: @ Close voters, OP is attempting to find a product type to fit a problem (size), not a specific product or place. This puts it on the ***on topic side*** of the close reason.

Comment: @Passerby I always thought that requests for a part which fits a certain spec is exactly what this close reason is for.

Comment: @Dmitry read the close reason and the link it includes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many available that are smaller than the standard 5050 (5mm x 5mm) 3 diode led package size. 3535 and 2020 (2mm x 2mm) addressable leds are available on a few markets. You want to look for smd led package sizes or codes, and add "addressable led".  These have the same or similar type of interface as other APA or WS protocols.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it is just a weird thing to try and search to find information about so I appreciate it

Comment: @ReeseHouseknecht I understand, not knowing the terms to use make it difficult. Good luck

Answer (score 2):

2 mm x 2 mm [APA102-202 RGB LED](http://www.led-color.com/upload/201604/APA102-2020%20SMD%20LED.pdf)

[image]

[image]

Used in the [Adafruit DotStar](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Adafruit%20PDFs/3587_Web.pdf) products.
[image]

---

See more at Digikey.

LINK: [Digikey Addressable RGB LEDs](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/optoelectronics/addressable-specialty/126?k=&pkeyword=&pv1989=0&sf=0&FV=9406ab%2C94030c%2C1140003%2Cffe0007e%2Cb844fa%2Cb8649d%2Cb88c3c%2Cb8afe1&quantity=&ColumnSort=46&page=1&pageSize=250)

---

The Ultimate RGB Lighting

Use 1.8 mm x 1.8 mm [Luxeon Color C Line](https://www.lumileds.com/uploads/571/DS144-pdf)  LEDs with color mixing optics.

[image]

Use 2 red, 2 blue, and 1 green.
I prefer the deep red and royal blue.

Drive them with a [TI TLC5973  3-Channel LED Driver](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlc59731.pdf)

[image]

The above driver is only 50 mA and the Color C will be very bright.
They will be much brighter if driven with a 700 mA driver with a PWM control pin.

---

This circuit uses the TLC5973 to drive an LM3414 driver or a Mean Well LDD-700H dimmable LED driver.

[image]

---

This is three 450 nm royal blue driven at only 10 mA.

[image]

---

sixteen 660 nm deep red driven at 700 mA.

[image]